# Why $u=|v|^{p-2}v\implies v=|u|^{\frac{2-p}{p-1}}u$?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $p>1$. Why $$u=|v|^{p-2}v\implies v=|u|^{\frac{2-p}{p-1}}u.$$

The thing I have is $$u=|v|^{p-2}v\implies u=\pm |v|^{p-1}\implies |v|^{p-1}=|u|\implies v=\pm|u|^{\frac{1}{p-1}}.$$

Comment: What are $u$ and $v$?  Numbers?  Ordered $n$-tuples?  Functions?

Comment: The simplest assumption would be numbers, and the question works that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So far so good.

Now we also know $|v|^{p-2} \ge 0$ and thus
$$\mathrm{sgn}(u) = \mathrm{sgn}(v)$$
Using this and
$$|v| = |u|^{\frac1{p-1}} = |u|^{\frac{1 - (p-1)}{p-1}+1} = |u|^{\frac{2-p}{p-1}+1} = |u|^{\frac{2-p}{p-1}}|u|$$
you can conclude.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: $\frac{1}{p-1} = \frac{2-p}{p-1} +1 $